# zf create controller About - getting a 404 - why?

Tags: zend-framework

I've done the following command:

```
zf create controller About
```

So, zend tool have created a controller, a index action a index view.

If I then go to:
http://mysite.dev/about/

I got a 404 error.

Is this due to the fact that, on the Index action of my AboutController, I don't have nothing that says "go look into the view" ?

If so, what should I put on that action, in order to get the view displayed and NOT a 404 ?

On my .htaccess file, located here: *~/public_html/mysite.dev/public/* I have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

#hotlinking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.dev [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.something\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In */etc/apache2/sites-available* I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysite.dev

DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/mysite.dev/public

<Directory /home/user/public_html/mysite.dev/public>
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that, on this configuration, when I type the command to create a new zend project I DO GET the initial Zend page correctly called.

**Update:**

I've change the following lines on the .htaccess file and NOW it's working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

So I've added a -s flag and a -l flag, and I take out the negation of -d flag and the line containing the !-f flag.

The point for having the !-d and the !-f was that of allowing access to directories and files without those to being redirected. So that, if it's a file and if exists, then, don't redirect. If is something else that is not a file nor a directory (ie. a controller call), then redirect.

I'm not getting why, with this change, I got it working. :(

**Why?**

Thanks again.

Comment: is the .htaccess setup correctly and url rewriting available on the vhost? a new empty action will display the new empty view... not a 404 error.

Comment: hhmmm... so I have an issue there... :( I will update my question and paste htaccess file and vhost information. Thanks

Comment: Is it a Zend error controller 404 or an apache 404?

Comment: It's an Apache 404 :( So that could mean that the issue may be related with the .htaccess file somehow. A wrong redirection. Perhaps is thinking that about is a directory ?

Comment: It sounds like the rewriting isn't working at all. What happens if you try something random as a url, like mysite.dev/asdfsadf/ - it should display a Zend 404 if it's working.

Comment: mod rewrite is enabled. I have changed the .htaccess file and It's working now. I'm just not understanding why. :) I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} **!**-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} **!**-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The erorr is in the exclamation mark in RewriteCond, you said to apache that if the request filename isnt a directory and isn't a regular file to go straight, otherwise go to index.php.

You need to invert them like you already done in the new htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Two questions then: 1) Why do we need those -s and -l flags ? 2) I thought that I was telling, if the request filename isn't a directory nor a regular file, then, rewrite. Where can we read the "go straight" part ? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: The "go straight" (sry for my bad english) is this line:
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L], the first 3 rows are useful when you are lookin for a physic file in the public directory like images, css etc..without redirecting to the index.php

Comment: I've a bad english myself so, worry not. :) And where can we read the "otherwise" ? We have 3 conditions and two rules, is the second rule only applied if the first rule doesn't ?

Comment: Yes sir, the first rule is applied if one of the 3 RewriteCond is true (because there's an [OR]), otherwise the second one